# Removing 10px of margin at top of HTML pages

Tags: html, css

I have a very simple HTML page with a very simple stylesheet. The page has a margin of `10px` at the top that won't go away. Here are my layout and styles:

```
html, body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    margin-top: -10px;
}

.main-container {
  with: 100%;
}

.left-column {
  width: 25%;
  float: left;
  background-color: lightblue;
  height: 500px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

and here is my HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
  <body>
    <main class="main-container">
      <aside class="left-column">

      </aside><!-- .left-column -->
      <section class="news-feed">
        <article class="story-item">
          <header class="story-title">
            <h1>This is the title of the post</h1>
          </header><!-- .story-title -->
          <p class="story-details">
            This is the body of the post
          </p>
        </article><!-- .story-item -->
      </section><!-- .news-feed -->
    </main><!-- .main-container -->
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It may be a browser-specific problem beyond your control. You can try `margin: 0 !important; padding:0 !important;`, which might overrule user styles.

Comment: Make `h1` `margin-top:0`

Comment: What browser are you seeing this in?

Comment: This is the issue caused by `float:left` in `.left-column`!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The H1 tag has a standard margin of 10px which causes this.  Try a reset:

```
*,html,body {
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
```

The "*" character is a global selector.

Comment: That was it! Thanks! I'll give you the checkmark in 5 minutes with the time limit expires

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
body {    
    margin: 0 !important;
    padding: 0 !important;
}
```

Comment: !important, especially in this situation, is bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

Use a reset or normalise.css

or this will normally work.

```
body {
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the default style on the h1 tag use:

```
h1 {margin:0px;}
```